# What are the ways to avoid !! in Kotlin code?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am reviewing a piece of code where Lottie is used 
Here is the code

```
class ProgressToProgress(context: Context) : LottieIconTransition(
LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(
    context, R.raw.downloadprogress).value!!)
```

where

```
  @Nullable public V getValue() {
return value;}
```

this `getValue()` method is  from Lottie library so I don't any control over it.
what I don't like that there is !! in the above and interestingly the constructor of `LottieIconTransition` looks like this it has default param for it constructor param

`class LottieIconTransition(private val lottieComposition: LottieComposition = LottieComposition())`

I would like to know what could be the best practise to avoid having !! in code?

Comment: What does a null value represent in this case? Instead of asserting not null (which doesn't give you any useful information in case the value is null), you can throw something more concrete, for example `value ?: error("Failed to load transition.")`.

Comment: View can be null, but you can see the constructor LottieIconTransition  has default value, I am wondering if the passing param is null will it crash or constructor will take default value?

Comment: No it will crash. If you want to use a default value do `.value ?: <insert default value>`.

Comment: So with this existing logic having in constructor default value doesn't make sense, yes ?
but what if I do just null assertion and in case null I will not pass it to constructor and as the constructor has default value. and this constructor is used by others as well , I don't want to do changes for now.

Comment: `!!` (null assertion) will throw an exception if the value is null. I won't result in "no value being passed allowing default constructor value to be used". The instant you specify an argument on a parameter with a default value, the default value will never get used.

Comment: I meant checking if(value !=null){pass value } else{ do nothing } and in this case it will use default  value.

Comment: No that's no possible. Use a factory method in the companion object that calls the constructor appropriately: calls it without argument if the value is null, otherwise pass the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I meant by using a factory method.

```
class ProgressToProgress {

    constructor() : super()
    constructor(res: LottieResult<LottieComposition>) : super(res)

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun create(context: Context): ProgressToProgress {
            val res = LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(
                    context, R.raw.downloadprogress).value
            return if (res == null) {
                ProgressToProgress()
            } else {
                ProgressToProgress(res)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it's a lot of trouble, you might want to specify the default value yourself i.e.:

```
class ProgressToProgress(context: Context) : LottieIconTransition(
        LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(
            context, R.raw.downloadprogress).value ?: <respecify super default parameter value>)
```